# How do I change date/time format via command prompt/powershell?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line

I'm trying to automate my PC setup as much as possible and I'm wondering if it's possible to change the date/time format via the command line.

If yes, I would like to know the command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The date/time format is encoded as part of the *region*. You can set this from the CLI via the PowerShell [`Set-Culture`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852137.aspx) cmdlet. This is part of the [`International`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852115.aspx) module available since Windows 8/Server 2012. You are basically looking for the equivalent of the GUI Control Panel Region applet (which can be displayed with `control /name Microsoft.RegionAndLanguage`).

---

## Example

For the impatient, the basic PowerShell command is:

```
$culture = Get-Culture
$culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = 'd/MM/yyyy'
Set-Culture $culture
```

There are some other date/time patterns I've listed down the bottom that you might wish to modify.

---

## Details

First, if you're on Windows 8, you'll need to import the module. This is not necessary on Windows 10.

```
Import-Module International
```

---

Now, if you wanted to change your entire region, you can do that in a single command, e.g.:

```
Set-Culture 'en-AU'
```

You [can use](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky2chs3h(v=vs.110).aspx) any valid [BCP-47](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47) tag here. Note that this will also change other region-related settings, such as the decimal separator.

This is the approach I would recommend most of the time, unless you have specific needs otherwise.

---

If you want to more specifically control the date/time format, you'll need to either construct your own [`CultureInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) object or take the current culture and modify it:

```
$culture = Get-Culture
$culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = 'd/MM/yyyy'
Set-Culture $culture
```

---

#### Relevant date/time properties

You can see the list of existing options by just running `$culture.DateTimeFormat` (or `Get-Culture.DateTimeFormat`). The ones you might want to modify are:

```
FullDateTimePattern
LongDatePattern
LongTimePattern
ShortDatePattern
ShortTimePattern
```

I would recommend not touching the RFC1123 pattern and the sortable patterns.

Comment: What about from WSH (windows scripting host)?

Comment: @RemusRigo You're probably better off asking a new specific question for that. Though if you're referring to the wscript/cscript engines, those run off VBScript so that might help your searching.

Answer (score 0):

If the lower right date format of the Windows UI does not change after the above method, enter it in the command as shown below.

```
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v sShortDate /d "d/MM/yyyy" /f
```